# different Time Zones in android

Tags: java, android, time

my application saves local time using OnStart() method and i am using this code below to convert time to "time ago" but when two persons from different time zones this method does not work it always shows **incorrect** time ago

```
private void updateUserStatus(String state)
{
    String lastSeenTime;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    lastSeenTime = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    HashMap<String,Object> onlineStatemap = new HashMap<>();
    onlineStatemap.put("lastSeen", lastSeenTime);
    onlineStatemap.put("state", state);
    if (firebaseUser != null )
    {
        currentUserID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("userState").updateChildren(onlineStatemap);

    }

}



private String calculateTime(String lastSeenTT)
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        long time = sdf.parse(lastSeenTT).getTime();
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CharSequence ago =
                DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
        return ago+"";
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}


 String timeAgo = calculateTime(lastSeenTT);
```

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) (for early Android versions too). It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between ( then , Instant.now() )
```

## Details

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

Use an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds when capturing a moment. For that, `Instant` class.

```
Instant then = Instant.now() ;
…
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

`Duration` class represents elapsed time on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Duration d = Duration.between ( then , now ) ;
```

Notice that no time zones were involved.

Track your date-time values as *java.time* objects, not text. Generate text only as needed for logging, debugging, and presentation to the user.

---

The *java.time* classes are built into Android 26+. For earlier Android, the “desugaring” features in the latest tooling makes available most of the *java.time* functionality.

Comment: This method needs Android Api 26 which is Android OREO so older version won't work

Comment: @recycle Reread my Answer more carefully, all the way through.

Comment: Also , looks this method doesn't represent the FULL date , "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: @recycle You asked for elapsed time, not a date-time. Again, reread my Answer more carefully. You need no strings nor text to track two moments and their elapsed time.

Comment: I published my code which contain `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: @recycle That Line of your code generating text is irrelevant to your problem. Learn to think in objects, not strings.

Comment: I did not mention my line of code to say it's better than yours !! i mention it to prove that i need full DATE and TIME with this format.

Comment: Why you are deleting and editing your comments so much? first this is not schoolwork second, I didn't ask you to do anything for me  i just having discussion about your -Perfect method-

Answer (score 1):

When you store the time, you need to store in UTC. Retrieve it from server in UTC format. While displaying last seen , convert it to local time zone of that displaying device.